# How to show data from sqlite3 with electron5 and angular8

Tags: angular, sqlite, electron

I'm new to electron5 and angular8.
I have retrieved data from sqlite3, but I can't get arround how to send this data to my angular part and show it.

I have tried using observables, but being new to them, I'm not sure I did it right. I also tried various async codes, pipes, maps, types changes, etc... I found but to no avail.

Here is my electron.service file that retrieves the data from the sqlite3 db (the console.log works), with some commented test code :

```
Read() {
    //var db = new sqlite3.Database("./dosimetre.sqlite");
    let db = new this.sqlite3.Database(
      "./dosimetre.sqlite",
      this.sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE,
      err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        } else {
          console.log("Connected to the dosi database.");
        }
      }
    );
    let data = [];
    let sql = "SELECT code FROM INDIVIDU LIMIT 0,5";
    //let sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
    db.each(sql, (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      data.push(row);
    });
    db.close(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log("Close the database connection.");
    });
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      observer.next(data);
    });
    //return data;
  }
}
```

My home.component.ts, the "this.list" is shown, but not the "this.rows$"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ElectronService } from "../../providers/electron.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.scss"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ElecServ: ElectronService) {}
  rows$ = [];
  list = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = [{age: 32,},{age: 25,},{age: 32,}];
    //this.rows = this.ElecServ.Read();
    this.ElecServ.Read().subscribe(x => {
      this.rows$ = x;
    });
    //this.ElecServ.Read();
    console.log("test2", this.rows$);
    //console.log("test", this.list);
    //console.log("data test", this.ElecServ.Read());
  }
  //ngDoCheck(){}
}
```

And my home.component.html that shows the list but not the rows$

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    List of users
  </h1>
  <ul *ngIf="list">
    <li *ngFor="let array of list">{{ array.age }}</li>
  </ul>
  <ul *ngIf="ElecServ.rows$ | async as rowing">
    <li *ngFor="let array2 of rowing.rows$">{{ array2.code }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm expecting a list of 5 "codes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sqlite 3 query are asynchronous.

You send empty data to your view.

I sugest you tou use promise with async/await syntaxe like below :

```
Read() {

return new
Promise(resolve
=> {

let data = [];

//var db = new sqlite3.Database("./dosimetre.sqlite");

let db =
new this.sqlite3.Database(

"./dosimetre.sqlite",

this.sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE,

err => {

if (err) {

console.error(err.message);

} else {

console.log("Connected to the dosi database.");

}

}

);



let sql =
"SELECT code, id, nom FROM INDIVIDU LIMIT 0,5";

//let sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";



db.each(sql, (err,
row) => {

if (err) {

console.error(err.message);

}

data.push(row);

});



db.close(err
=> {

if (err) {

console.error(err.message);

}

console.log("Close the database connection.");
// Resolve your promise here
resolve(data);

});

});
```